# Firefox keyboard shortcut to switch search engines in search bar

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser

I would like to know if there is a keyboard shortcut for switching the search engine in the search bar in Firefox. The current way to do is clicking on the down arrow beside the icon, but I am looking for a quick keyboard shortcut.

Checked the Firefox help, it just has [this](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/search-bar-easily-choose-your-search-engine#w_switching-search-engines) regarding the switching of search engines in search bar.

I need this, as I need to frequently switch between Google and the internal intranet search engine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Click at the icon
2. Select "Manage Search Engines…"
3. Select the search engine you want to set a shortcut for
4. Click on "Edit keyword…"
5. Give a shortcut, e.g. "g" for Google

Now you can type into the address bar the chosen search shortcut followed by what you like to search. Example: `g weather berne`.

To switch to the address bar with the keyboard, use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. You could also open a new tab (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), because it sets the focus to the address bar automatically.

---

By the way: this works for nearly all search fields on any website. Just right-click on a search field and select "Add a keyword for this search…" (don't know the actual English translation). Instead of adding this search to the search widget, Firefox saves it as a bookmark.

Comment: Perfect.......:)

Comment: The universal 'Add a keyword' is really helpful. Didn't know about it. Thanks

Comment: this doesn't work anymore. I wonder why firefox has removed it... My workflow has slow down a bit since they removed this.

Comment: @David天宇Wong: I can’t test the new version currently, but I assume you only refer to the first solution (via search engine) I described, right? Hopefully the second solution (via bookmark) still works. I think it [was never really needed to offer two different ways](http://superuser.com/a/793767/151741) to achieve almost the same.

Comment: @unor wow! I didn't see that second part of your answer. This is awesome, and so secretely hidden. How do you erase that if you don't want it anymore?

Comment: @David天宇Wong: It’s just a bookmark, so you can delete it (or edit the keyword) via the *Bookmarks* menu.

Answer (score 6):

In newer versions of Firefox, the shortcut you are looking for is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>.

Comment: in previous versions with the old search bar it's also Alt+Up/Down. I didn't notice that this also work for the new one, because now the search engines are listed horizontally

Comment: Confirmed this is the case, at least for firefox60esr onwards

Answer (score 5):

There is a shortcut for exactly this task: from the search bar, press control + Down(Next)/Up(Previous).

Comment: cntrl + Down/Up is not working anymore since version 34.0. Does anybody know how to do it now?

Comment: Firefox 34+ can still do this if you use [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/manage-search-engines-button/), see [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/854142/130012).

Comment: @WilfredHughes Thank you, but I do like the new search bar.However, I'm missing to have a shortcut again for changing from one search engine to another before to write the search phrase.
The workaround it's to use the <kbd>tab</kbd> button once you're on the search bar and the <kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>down</kbd> arrow keys. More info [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1035085?utm_campaign=questions-reply&utm_medium=email&utm_source=notification)

Answer (score 4):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to focus on the search bar and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> as per Akronix's answer.

Unor's method in conjunction with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is of course a lot faster for everyday use.

Comment: notice that now ctrl + E doesn't open the search bar anymore, only ctrl + K does.