# Firefox: Add a custom Google search including pre-defined keywords

Tags: firefox, search-engines, google-search

I'd like to figure out a way to have customized Google searches to choose from in the Firefox search bar in the top right corner. By customized I just mean the possibility to add specific pre-defined keywords which would then be appended automatically to the performed Google search.

For example, if I am looking for movie subtitles, I'd just like to be able to select my custom made "Google Subtitles Search" that would just magically add a "subtitle" keyword to the search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ready2search: http://ready.to/search/en/

Or you can use searchplugins.net: http://www.searchplugins.net/generate.aspx

Here's an answer detailing how to use searchplugins.net: https://superuser.com/a/306467/33303

Comment: Where do you enter the additional keywords in any of these forms?

Comment: @Steve06: In ready2search, the specified keywords are appended to the prefix that you specify. So if you wanted to use google, your prefix would be ```http://google.com/search?q=```. On searchplugins.net the string "TEST" is replaced with your search terms, in the URL. So on searchplugins.net, your "Search URL" would be ```http://google.com/search?q=TEST```

Comment: searchplugins.net worked well for me and your explanation was fine, except that I had to figure out that if you have several additional keywords, you have to separate them with "%20" instead of spaces. But good stuff anyway!

Answer (score 1):

The [Mycroft Project generator](http://mycroft.mozdev.org/submitos.html) should help you generate plugins that will add custom search engines to your browser. The linked page is well-documented itself.

Comment: Where do you enter the additional keywords in that form?

Comment: For a google search with 'subtitle' your `Search URL` should look something like this:
https://encrypted.google.com/search?as_q=subtitle+{searchTerms}

Comment: This one probably works too but the form is too complicated and takes too long to fill out.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to [use the address bar to search various websites](https://superuser.com/a/475626/151741) (works for every input field!), which is much faster to use than using the custom search bar.

It saves the searches as bookmarks, which allows you to edit the bookmark and change its URL to insert anything you want.

#### Example

A search bookmark for DuckDuckGo might have this URL (where `%s` is the placeholder for your search):

```
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%s
```

Now you could copy this bookmark entry, set a different search keyword and change the URL so that it only searches pages on superuser.com (by using the `site:` operator):

```
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site:superuser.com %s
```

Comment: I know that trick and got it already implemented. I see both tricks as complementary, since I can easily assign a keyword to my new custom search engine.