# What is the difference between Firefox search engine keywords and bookmark keywords?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, search-engines, keyword

I know the obvious answer is: One is for search engines and the other is for all kinds of bookmarks. But I'm referring to the "Add a keyword for this search" functionality when right-clicking input fields.

Both give me the possibility to type sth like `su windows` in the addressbar to perform a Superuser search for a specific query. One time it's using an extra bookmark, the other time it's using a search engine entry.

I found various sites like [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/114447/how-to-speed-up-web-browsing-with-search-bookmark-keywords) describing both ways of adding keywords.

However I'm wondering what the actual difference is and which way is preferable. Since my bookmarks get synchronized through Sync and my search engines don't, I don't see any reason to use the search engines at all and could remove the field from the toolbar. Aren't the search-engines just a subset of the bookmark keywords?

Answer (score 2):

I think your observation is correct: [two different ways for essentially the same thing](https://superuser.com/a/475626/151741).

Advantages for the search field way:

- The searches added via bookmark can only be used via keyboard shortcuts, while the search fields in the toolbar can also be used when you don’t want to use keyboard shortcuts.

Advantages for the bookmark way:

- Not all input fields offer [OpenSearch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSearch), but every input field can be added as a bookmark search.
- Bookmarks can be synchronized with Firefox Sync, while this [currently not possible](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=444284) for the search engines.
- Bookmarks can be edited more easily: you can change the search URL within the GUI (which allows you to make [searches with pre-defined search terms](https://superuser.com/a/488050/151741)).

Comment: This is a very good pro/cons list and basically confirms my current impression. Then I'm just wondering why the more tedious search engines still exist, if their only advantage is the more obvious usage.