# Search engine short-cut missing in Firefox 34

Tags: firefox, shortcuts, search-engines

In the past version of Firefox you could define short-cuts for search engines. (by clicking on the black small arrow/triangle) and then "Manage Search Engines" - then you could define short-cuts)

**This allowed typing the short-cut character followed by a space and then the search phrase in the address bar.**

With the update to Firefox version 34 the option to define a short-cut is gone. Old short-cuts defined in previous version are working though.

So **how can you define short-cuts for search engines in Firefox 34** (and later)?

I noticed this change today (2014-12-18) in the standards release version 34 and developer edition 36.0a2. I wonder why they changed it in both versions and how to define short-cuts from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the **["Manage Search Engines" button](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/manage-search-engines-button/)** extension, it will put a button that works like the pre-v34 drop-down button (the black triangle) in the search bar, giving you access to 'Manage Search Engines'.

Alternatively, go to `about:config` in the address bar and type `browser.search.showOneOffButtons` in the 'Search:' form. Double-click  or right-click » toggle the resulting row to change its value to 'false'. This will restore the search bar back to its pre-Firefox 34 version, also restoring the drop-down button and 'Manage Search Engines'.

Answer (score 2):

Up until now, Firefox provided [two different ways](https://superuser.com/a/475626/151741) for specifying a shortcurt:

- via search engines
  (doesn’t work anymore by default; see [galacticninja’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/854142/151741) for getting back the old behaviour)
- via bookmarks
  ([should](https://superuser.com/questions/475625/firefox-keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-search-engines-in-search-bar/475626#comment1123706_475626) still work)

The *bookmarks way* has the advantage that [it’s much more powerful](https://superuser.com/a/793767/151741). Why?

- It works for *any* form input field.
- The site doesn’t have to explicitly support it.
- The shortcuts can be synchronized with Firefox Sync (as they are only bookmarks).
- You can edit the bookmarks easily, which allows you to [specify pre-defined search terms](https://superuser.com/a/488050/151741), for example.

How?

1. Right-click on any input field.
2. Select "Add a keyword for this search…" (or similar).
3. Enter the shortcurt (and optionally: edit the generated search URL to include pre-defined search terms).

This gets saved as a usual bookmark in a bookmark folder of your choice.

Comment: Very good explanation - this really helps to solve the issue and even saves time to add search engines after a fresh installation. Thx