# How to disable the new one-click search bar interface in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: firefox

My main Ubuntu desktop received an update of Firefox with the new one-click search interface a few weeks ago. I gave it a try, but I still cannot get used to the current implementation.

I previously used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to access the search bar and switched providers with <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd>. I thought using only <kbd>↑</kbd> to start at the end of the list when suggestions are displayed would work for selecting non-default providers, but correcting your search query and having to select the non-default provider again makes it a bit tedious.

I will try again in new releases.

[image: example from the Mozilla UX blog]

Comment: Related: [Search engine short-cut missing in Firefox 34](http://superuser.com/q/854125/10259)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To revert back to the old behavior:

1. Go to `about:config`.
2. Search for `browser.search.showOneOffButtons` and set it to `false`.
3. You need to **restart** your browser, otherwise you may experience issues like only having one search provider.

The behavior has been improved since the feature was introduced:

- Providers can be switched with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd>.
- It doesn't reset to the default provider for every query anymore. It remembers the previously selected provider.
- A site can be added to this list of search providers if it supports OpenSearch. This functionality has been available in earlier versions but was removed in Firefox 4.